# fancybox unexpectedly reload content after click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

After each click on any element inside fancybox content it reload this content. What i doing wrong?

hidden content in page body (display: none;):

```
<div class="fancybox page" id="trans_page">
    Вы выбрали <span class="post_count">0</span> материалов.
    <br><br>
    <select id="editor_id_trans">
        {foreach $editors as $item}
            <option value="{$item.id}">{$item.author} - {$item.name} №{$item.id}</option>
        {foreachelse}
            <option>Нет ни одного копирайтера.</option>
        {/foreach}
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <button class="btn btn-default">направить</button>
</div>
```

code to show this content in fancybox:

```
function go_trans(){   
    $.fancybox($("#trans_page"));        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fancybox({
    type: 'inline',
    href: '#your-inline-div'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function go_trans(){
     $.fancybox.open([{
                  href :'#trans_page'                 
           }]);
}
```

Heres a jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/wg4MD/

if your still stuck, have a look at the documentation.

http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful

Comment: James Nicholson, it opens, but same bug with reloadings on click

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem, i must not use "fancybox" class in div with content i need to show. Change to this:

```
<div class="fancybox_page" id="trans_page">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what worked best for me was adding an afterShow function:

```
$("#container").fancybox({
    afterShow:function(){
        $('#container').click(function(){return false;});
    }
});
```